# How to have leading zeroes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2000

Table1

```
ID

001
0569
897
....
```

ID Lenght should be 4, if the lenght is 3 then it should add '0' in front.

How to do this.

Need Query Help

Comment: what is the type of Id Field ?

Comment: If ID is a integer field someone neeeds a SQL book,. It sounds to me like this should be a string field (char(4)). I bet it is something smart like int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/10/sql-server-pad-ride-side-of-number-with-0-fixed-width-number-display/) for two methods. Summarized:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) FROM Table1
```